# access: best way of allowing users to simultaneously edit table?

Tags: ms-access, vba

i have an access front end. users need to be able to open a table and edit the contents of a table. this is a multi-user application. please note that i do not care that i might run into problems with people editing the same data.

1. how do i allow a user who only has the access RUNTIME to be able to edit and view a table?
2. how do i force the table to be open when access opens>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a form. This can be loaded as the start-up form. This would be a fairly standard way to use Access with a runtime version. Ensure you include all buttons that the user will need. You can test with the runtime switch: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207

Answer (score 1):

*# how do i allow a user who only has the access RUNTIME to be able to edit and view a table?*

a custom UI, such as one built in vb.net?

*how do i force the table to be open when access opens?*

autoexec macro?

Comment: Er, with the Access runtime, why would you need VB.NET? And what does an AutoExec macro have to do with anything?

Comment: you'd need vb.net for the front end, or some other tool, if they didn't have Access installed, just the runtime.  If they do have Access installed (I wasn't clear on that myself, the questions seem to contradict each other) and you want anything to happen when Access opens, you can use the autoexec macro.

Comment: I think you need to read up on what the Access runtime is, @Beth. It *is* Access, binary-compatible with full Access, just configured so as to not give access to the interactive user interface. That is, the Access runtime can run an Access application without full Access being installed. And it's free. In other words, there is really no need at all for VB.NET to create a front end. This is not new -- the runtime has existed since at least Access 2 (c. 1994). What is new with A2007 is that it's now free (previously there was a reasonably $300 developer's license).

Comment: well, it may have changed, but from what I understood, the runtime had JET functions for tables & queries, but not Access UI features like forms or reports.  I'm not sure why he would emphasize that he's using the runtime if it doesn't limit his options.